# Generate primary keys without creating the record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I want to be able to do something like

```
@foo = MyClass.new
5.times do
  @foo.things.build
end
```

But my ***@foo*** needs to have a primary key for this to work, Soo what is the best way to generate primary keys without creating the object?

The purpose for this is to be able to use nested forms more easely

```
form_builder.fields_for :things do ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probable want is [NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent. By default nested attribute updating is turned off, you can enable it using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for class method`. When you enable nested attributes an attribute writer is defined on the model.

The implementation is different between each ORM, here is for **sequel** and **ActiveRecord**

NOTE: Full tutorial also available at [Nerdgem](http://www.nerdgem.com/tutorials/3-adding-nested-attributes-to-models)

### Sequel impementation

Imagine there is a Project class that has many tasks

```
class Project < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many :tasks
end

class Task < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :project
end
```

To enable the nested attributes you will need include two plugins for the Project class

- **Sequel::Plugins::NestedAttributes:**  allows you to create, update, and delete associated objects directly by calling a method on the current object. Nested attributes are defined using the nested_attributes class method:
- **Sequel::Plugins::InstanceHooks:** which is a dependency of NestedAttributes

You can find really good doc on the [plugin site](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins.html)

```
Project.plugin :instance_hooks
Project.plugin :nested_attributes
```

After that is done you can call  the `nested_attributes` method on the desired class

```
Project.nested_attributes :tasks
```

Now you can do this

```
p = Project.new(:title=>'Project')
p.tasks_attributes = [{:title=>'First Task'}, {:title=>'Second Task'}]
puts p.tasks.inspect
# It will output this
# [#<Task @values={:title=>"First Task"}>, #<Task @values={:title=>"Second Task"}>]
```

When you save the project it will save both the project and the tasks.

If you can even to edit many tasks at the same.

### ActiveRecord implementation

Here is how to use it.

Imagine there is a Project class that has many tasks

Project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
end
```

Task.rb

```
class Tasks < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :project_id
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Now you can do this.

```
p =  Project.new
p.tasks_attributes=[{title: "First Task"}]

p.things
# Would output this
#=> [#<Thing id: nil, title: "First Task", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, bar_id: nil>]
p.save
```

When you save the project it will save both the project and the tasks.

If you want to edit many project tasks at the same time you can to this

```
p.tasks_attributes=[{title: "First Task"},{title: "Second Task"}]
```

NOTE: there is also a Railscasts that can help you out with nested forms. [Orginal Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), [Revised Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)

Comment: I've edited and added the sequel implementation also. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Very extensive answare!, I did went for active record for the project but I will try out your answare! :)

Comment: This perhaps is a good answer for 2012, but for a long time now - since 2012 more or less - https://codeclimate.com/blog/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ - nested attributes is increasingly considered a very niche tool for simple purposes that you need to switch out the moment your life becomes complicated. Once this happens - you need to actually prefetch the IDs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the OP is asking for how to **initialize** a view action property for use in **new** action for a standard Rails resource. At this point, there is no ID for the main parent. The solution is simple:

The model:

```
class ParentObject < ActiveRecord::Base
    # the child model in this example is called child_objects
    has_many :child_objects, :dependent => :destroy 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :child_objects
```

The controller action for new:

```
@object = Object.new :example_field => "my field"
@object.child_objects.build :name => "value_1" # pretending that name is a field
@object.child_objects.build :name => "value_2"
```

Then, in the view:

```
= form_for(@object) do |f| # top level Object
    = f.label :example_field
    = f.text_field :example_field

    =# the next line loops twice in this example
    = f.fields_for :child_objects do |child| 
        = child.label :name
        = child.text_field :name
```

There is also a good gem called nested_form written by Ryan Bates (https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) which may help you with the rest of the CRUD operations.